# When to use "have" and "have got"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, have-got

When do I use *have* and *have got*?

Are "I have the answer" and "I've got the answer" both correct?

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/ive-got-vs-ive-gotten/5536#5536).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have the answer

sounds more formal and somber, and it is often used as a statement of fact or as a direct response to the questions: *Do you have the answer?*  *Who has the answer?* etc.

> I've got the answer/I have got the answer

is more of an eureka moment remark, something one is likely to hear often in such a place as a college physics common room where students are bashing heads on seemingly intractable problems.

The *have got* construction is more of a Britishism. In the US, one would be more likely to hear:

> I got the answer/Got the answer

Comment: Is "I've the answer" considered grammatical?

Comment: *I've the answer* is grammatical but certainly not colloquial, i.e. it is an expression you would definitely not hear from a native speaker. The contraction *I've* usually precedes the past participle, e.g. *I've been*, *I've had*, *I've seen*, *I've taken*, etc. In this case, *I've got the answer* is more natural. So is *I have the answer.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply =) Btw, if what I wanted to say is that "I have a habit *presently*", is there a difference in meaning between saying "I've got a habit of *something*" and "I've a habit of *something*"? (is the second one colloquial?)

Comment: No difference. The *I've got...* is more of a British construction, really. *I've a habit of...* would certainly be considered colloquial, depending on where you are, though it's not a construction I use often... If one is speaking fast enough, that could be tough. *I'm in the habit of...* is something I'm more likely to say, but that's just me. But in this case, both are certainly correct and sound natural.

Comment: But isn't *"I'm in the habit of collecting stamps."* odd-sounding?

Comment: Sometimes the got is omitted for style and/or brevity. Consider if if He-Man had raised his sword and said "By the power of Greyskull, I. Have. Got. The. Powaaaah!!!"

Comment: In American English, *I "got" the answer* would not be standard but extremely slang or dialectal. The norm is *I have the answer.*

Comment: Really depends on context here... I do agree *have* can be routine. Usually, one hears/uses *I have it/I got it/Got it*, etc... *I got the answer* could also be argued for as a normal response in a situation where students are discussing answers to graded questions, in which case *right/correct* might also be used as modifiers. Anyway, to clarify, my final example were offered in contrast to the *have got* construction, which is rarely heard in regular spoken conversation. *I have the answer* is still quite formal even here in the US.

Comment: @Pacerier "I'm in the habit of collecting stamps" is odd because stamp-collecting is not a *habit* so much as a *hobby*. However, I suppose you might say "I'm in the habit of" when you were referring to something which you do as a pastime, but such that you *expect that pastime to be not particularly long-lasting*.

Comment: @Pacerier A standalone "I've the answer." sounds extremely awkward even to Brits. "I did _some_ research – I've the answers to several of the questions." sounds a lot less awkward, at least to my ears. But for the standalone sentence, "I've got the answer/s" or in a formal register "I have the answer/s."

Answer (score 10):

"Have got" is certainly more informal.  So if you never use "have got", you will be fine.  However, if you want to use "have got", this is how it works.

*Have* and "have got" are sometimes interchangeable and sometimes not.

When *have* is being used as a modal verb (or helper verb), then you **cannot** use "have got".

> - I have been there before.
> - *I have got been there before.  *(wrong)*

When have is being used as a main verb, you can replace it with "have got", **but only in the present tense**.

This is true for possessive uses of *have*:

> - I have three dollars.
> - I have got three dollars.
> - *I had got three dollars. *(wrong, if you mean possession and not acquisition)*
> - *I will have got three dollars. *(same as above)*

And also obligation:

> - I have to go.
> - I have got to go.
> - *I had got to go. *(wrong)*
> - *I will have got to go. *(wrong)*

Lastly, if you are constructing an imperative sentence, you can only use *have*:

> - Here, have an apple.
> - *Here, have got an apple. *(wrong)*

---

*A note on "have got" when referring to acquisition: this is not possible in US/Canadian English, where "have gotten" is the preferred form.*

Comment: Permit me to disagree with your closing note. *Have got* certainly exists in US English, even in situations dealing with acquisition. For instance, one would sooner hear "She's got the skills we need" than "She's gotten the skills we need". You may argue that this is not quite acquisition. However, I would still argue that "I've got it", especially when referring to answers/solutions is not unheard of in the US. Maybe this is a regional thing...

Comment: I'm going to disagree with your ban on using *had got* for possession. *"I had got three dollars in my pocket"* sounds fine to me, if somewhat informal (as a past tense for *have got* meaning possession). But **"will have got three dollars"* indeed sounds wrong.

Comment: "I've got three pounds" sounds far more natural than "I have got three pounds" in an unmarked sentence to my Br ears. "I have the answer" can sound stuffy.

Answer (score 2):

*I have the answer* and *I've got the answer* are both correct, yes.  The latter is more colloquial and informal; avoid it in formal writing.  Otherwise, use whatever sounds good to you at the time.