# What's the difference between "have" and "have got" to express possession?

Tags: grammar, expressions

What's the difference between "have" and "have got" to express possession?

examples:

1. I have a pen.
2. I have got a pen.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. See e.g. [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120721/have-vs-have-got-in-american-and-british-english) or [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11958/when-to-use-have-and-have-got), or the related questions linked from these. Please use the site search in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The to have in both sentences is not *really* the same verb. Rather a homonym (or more accurately secondary meanings) of the same verb.

I can better illustrate the difference by showing the equivalent translation into a Romance language ...

> Do you have a car?

Have is a verb meaning to possess. If translating you would use *tener* in Spanish.  (Less so in Italian, where you might use tenere, but would likely use avere instead.)  Tener in Spanish means to possess.

> Have you got a car?

Have is an auxiliary verb forming the present perfect tense. We would translate this sense of *have* into Spanish using *haber*, not *tener*. Again, Italian would use *avere*.  (Although, to be honest taken as a phrase I would translate to both languages as if it were the first question and ignore the present progressive.  A professional translator would likely preserve the tense as above, though.)

Got is the participle of to get.  So the question is *Did you acquire a car (at some point)?*  The effective meaning becomes *Do you possess a car.*

Comment: Some people consider auxiliaries a separate word-class from verbs.