# Can we call 'have got' as 'a verb' or it is not correct?

Tags: have-got

I’m an English volunteer teacher in a village school in Russia and I got the following phrase in the Russian state standard textbook of English for 6th form (12 year old students): ...a verb ‘have got’ is used….

Do you think it’s right to say that ‘have got’ is 'a verb'?
Or better to say that it’s a present perfect form of a verb ‘to get’
Or it’s a present perfect tense of a verb ‘to get’?

I think children can be confused when they see 2 verbs named as just 'a verb'.

Comment: "Have got" is not a verb, it's two verbs. Two different verb forms, too. Like "будет жевать" or "стал плясать". So what the book says is an oversimplification. Which depending on the target audience can be fine. What's not fine is that the oversimplification is ungrammatical. It should read "*the* verb 'have got' is used".

Comment: yes, it's a verb. and there are many posts about [have got](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=have+got) on this site. Basically, *have got* is a two-word version of *have* (present tense), in the sense of possession: I have two cars = I have got two cars = I've got two cars.

Comment: see amongst many others https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11958/when-to-use-have-and-have-got

Comment: and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76126/have-got-verb-form-and-tense

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Have got" — verb form and tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76126/have-got-verb-form-and-tense) and a zillion others

Comment: These students don't have any assumptions about English; if they're told _have got_ is a verb (which it is), they will just learn it. Think of it as an idiom, and an American one at that.

Comment: In "I've got a cold" in 'BrE', an all too common expression, 'have got' functions just as if it were a single-word verb. "I have a cold" is equally grammatical with an obvious single-orthographic-word verb (but sounds pretentious in most circumstances). Some analyses label the multi-word verb 'have got' a _verb_ . 'Make do' as in "We'll just have to make do [= manage] with what there is" is another two-word (apparently two-verb) combination that behaves as if it were a single verb. // Most native speakers don't ever think about the "Is it one verb? Two? Both" problem; it's 'just what we say'.

Comment: If you're asking whether the idiom "have got" is a compound verb, a single syntactic unit, then the answer is no. It consists of the auxiliary verb "have" + clausal complement with "got" as predicator (verb).

Answer (score 1):

In American English, *have got* behaves somewhat like a verb. Does this mean it is one? That depends on who you ask. But there is some justification for your textbook's position. However, as the OP says, calling *have got* a verb might be really confusing in ELL because there are lots of ways it doesn't behave like a verb. But calling it the present perfect might also be confusing for students of American English, because it doesn't behave like the present perfect in AmE, either.

Americans say (or at least some of us do)

> I've got the tickets, don't I?

If we thought of *have got* as the present perfect tense of *get*, we would say

> I've got the tickets, haven't I?

Furthermore, the actual past participle of the verb *get* (at least, when it means *acquire*) is *gotten*, and not *got*.

However, neither of these reasons for considering *have got* to be a verb holds in British English. So in British English, it may be better to think of it as the present perfect form of *to get*.

Comment: In 'BrE', contextless "I've got the tickets" is indeterminate between the senses "I have the tickets" and "I have acquired the tickets". The echo question would be "haven't I?" in either scenario.

Answer (score -1):

*I have  got*  is used  in simple  present   and  it  is  used instead  of  *have*  in informal situations  especially  in speech..Have( got)  is  a   verb and some grammarians call it idiom.

Have got is syntactically the present perfect in form but it is treated as the verb in the simple present.It is a combination of two verbs *have and got* but is used instead of *have* in the sense of possession

> I  have  a  daughter. (possession)
>
> I  have  got  a  daughter. (possession)
>
> I have  got  it. (I understand  it.)

You can not say *I have it* in the sense of *I understand it*

Both the  sentences which are used to indicate possession  mean  the  same  thing and  have  and  have got  are  two  forms   of  the  verb  have  in the  simple  present  form.They  are  used in the  sense  of  possession.

Have got  is not  a  single  verb but get is  not  the  past  participle  form of  get  here

Here is  a link  which  shows the  use  of   have   got.

https://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/grammar/beginner-grammar/have-got

Here  is  another  link:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/have-got-and-have

Comment: I would  like to  know  have  got  is  a   singular  verb form  which  is  equivalent  to  have  or  not.I would  like to  know  the  reason  for  downvoting.  Even John Lawler says  so.

Comment: I assume it's because <<  I have got is in used simple present form means I have..Have( got) is a verb or you may call it idiom. >> is poor English. People reading it are likely either to replicate the mistakes, or consider that maintaining standards on ELU is not considered a priority.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth. I agree that  what  you  habigtualy  say  is  correct.What  about  the  other  answers  which  you think  are  written in English  are  downvoted.What  I understand  is  your  voting  system is unreliable  because  If  we  say  they are  two  words, it  is  downvoted. If we  say  it  is  one word, it  is  down voted.Your  site  is  not  greater  than British council.We  can not  consider  the answers  authentic in any  competitive  exams  .They  are  just  opinions.Even  native  speakers  like  you  do  not  know what  it  is. It  is  a fact  that  I havegot is present tense

Comment: Neither the British Council article you mention nor the CED article have anything at all to say about 'have got' being a single verb or two verbs. So they fail to address OP's basic question. They merely explain how 'have got' is used by most (articulate) British native speakers. You need to go to more learned treatments (like McCawley or CGEL) to look at deeper analysis. // I was pointing out how poorly written your answer was as an attempt to explain a possible reason for the then -1 vote.

Comment: Please fix all the typos and formatting in your post. Also, "I have got it" does not mean "I understand it" to most native speakers; it means "I have it in my possession."

Comment: @ tchrist. The British council says  I have got it means  I have understood  also.

Answer (score -3):

I "have received" is finer in my opinion. In a case like " I **have got** the virus too." I'd offer the suggestion of dropping the word "got"; perhaps, or perhaps not,  replacing it with "contracted".

Comment: This isn't a general discussion site. Answers should answer the question asked. If the question had asked for general proof-reading that would be off topic.

Comment: thanks all. May be I didn't make key accent that it's a textbook FOR CHILDREN. Who don't know about present perfect, and Participle 2 of the verb "to get" and who will study it after TWO YEARS (by Russian state school schedule) - in such a case I am sure that it will make them confusing.  So in this way I think it's stupid to teach children in such a way. The problem in Russia is bad-bad textbooks monopolised by one business company. And students hate English lessons coz they don't understand it in school

Answer (score -3):

IMHO the answer is No. If we teach not english speaking children who even don't know what the heck is present perfect and Participle 2 it will break their brains when they see 2 verbs 'have got' but must call it 'a verb'. The problem is not a formal meaning if this can be called 'a verb' but result of teaching procedure.