# The North American use of "gotten" in the Passive Perfect Tenses

Tags: american-english, present-perfect, passive-voice, north-american-english

I am a British English Teacher, so I am not familiar with the North American use of "gotten" in the Passive Perfect Tenses. In these tenses, does the word "been" always get replaced by "gotten" in American English or is it sometimes a choice between "gotten" & "got"?

Here are some example sentences, can you give me the correct passive form in American English please?

> The flying car had been invented by Oleg before he died.
>
> The flying car had got \ gotten invented by Oleg before he died.

And

> The report has not been published by the government.
>
> The report has not got \ gotten published by the government.

Comment: Just a comment, but none of those seem right.  I haven’t thought a lot about it but I think I use gotten only in the sense of *acquired*.  “I had gotten this stuff last week before I realized  it was going to be on sale this week.”

Comment: I guess also in the sense of *to become*: It had gotten ruined in the wash.

Comment: I quit counting the duplicates on this site when I had gotten to 25. Please search for the earlier questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "I have got" and "I have gotten"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/difference-between-i-have-got-and-i-have-gotten)

Comment: Related: [“I've gotten better-looking as I get older”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199544/ive-gotten-better-looking-as-i-get-older-when-did-gotten-re-enter-the-breng)

Answer (score 2):

If it was a choice between *got* and *gotten* in these sentences, the right choice is *gotten*.

However, as the other comments and answers say, Americans would not use *gotten* for either of these sentences; the verb *been* is much better. Better examples would be

> She had gotten married the year before.
>
> I had gotten myself fired and was looking for work.