# Difference between "I've got a cold" and "I've gotten a cold" in American English

Tags: meaning, american-english

I once heard there is a difference in meaning between these two sentences in AmE. Is there any?

The possible duplicate [Difference between "I have got" and "I have gotten"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/difference-between-i-have-got-and-i-have-gotten) does not address this particular case.

Comment: Actually, it's fairly clearly covered by b.roth's answer.  To paraphrase, *gotten* can be used in the sense of *obtain*, but *gotten* is never used in the sense of possession.  Therefore, our sentences are equivalent to "I have a cold" and "I have obtained a cold." (or, more naturally, "I have caught a cold.")

Comment: This is covered in [this post](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gotten.html), which is for some reason the most popular thing on my Website.

Comment: Damn haters! Who does downvote such a good question? :) Thank you:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I have got" a cold means that you "caught" a cold and still "have" it, that is, you are still sick.

"I had" a cold means that, at some time in your life, probalby recently, you have "caught" a cold, but you no longer "have" it.

"I have gotten" a cold means that, at some time in your life, you have "caught" a cold.  You might or might not still "have" it.  So, it can mean either of the first two meanings.

In usage, "I have gotten" most often means the same as "I have got" and it is used to emphasize the "catching" of the cold over the "having" of the cold.  In particular, it often means that the person has only recently noticed that they have a cold.