# I get/got/'ve got/'ve gotten/have it

Tags: verbs, perfect-aspect

When you want to tell someone that you understand something, you might say, "I **get**/**got**/**'ve got** it." But

Q) Do we say "I'**ve gotten** it" or "I **have** it" in place of the above?

I ask this because, in "I get it", clearly, the main verb is "to get", and here, it means "to understand" (https://www.macmillandictionary.com/...ry/british/get), definition #7, but what about the rest? I mean, what is the main verb in "I've got it" or simply "I got it"? Is it "to get", as above, or is it "to have", as in "I have/'ve got/got a car?" (I know that "I **got** a car" is informal English, and mainly used in the US)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "I have got" and "I have gotten"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/difference-between-i-have-got-and-i-have-gotten) (b.roth's answer)

Comment: I posted on [this some years ago, here.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gotten.html)